# How to perform an AR query for multiple objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 different (ActiveRecord) models. Let's suppose they are called `Comment` and `Activity`. They have quite different attributes and methods. Also they both are associated with other models such as for example `Project`.

I am looking to define a method in the `Project` model so i can do something like:

```
Project.first.stream
```

That will return an ordered collection (f.e. based on the creation date of the underlying model) of all comments and activities associated with this specific project.

I can fetch the comments and activities separately and then order them in memory, but as the amount of records gets big fast this doesn't seem like a good solution.

Can anyone show me how this could be done in a way that will result in good performance and a minimum of hassle.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, you want to do the equivalent of:

```
def stream
  (comments + activities).sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

...but in AR?

Good question :-)

How are Comment and Activity associated to Project? It may be easiest to refactor your associations to have a polymorphic "Attaching" type of pattern, so that you can have an AttachedComment and an AttachedActivity, and all of them would be accessible though an "attachments" collection.